# string literals in C terminated with %?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm in the process of learning C and I ran into this weird problem with strings. I was playing around with strings and the different ways to declare strings and view their contents.

When declaring a string by using a char array and then printing each element of the array, it produced the expected output. It printed each character, finishing with the null character.

When declaring a string literal and printing out the contents of the resulting array, I noticed that a `%` character was appended on the string after the null byte.

Where is this `%` coming from?

The code is below. I compiled the code via;
`$ gcc nameStuff.c -o nameStuff`

I tried this on both my own Mac machine as well as a remote Linux server at school and got the same output both times.

Here's the code:

```
char myName[] = {72, 97, 121, 100, 101, 110, 0};    // my name in ASCII values
char *name = "Hayden";                              // my name as string literal

printf("%s, size: %ld\n", myName, sizeof(myName));  // 
printf("%s, size: %ld\n", name, sizeof(name));

int length1 = sizeof(myName);
int length2 = sizeof(name);
int i;

// prints char value of each element in ascii array
for (i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
    printf("%c,", myName[i]);
}
puts("");
// prints int value of each element in ascii array
for (i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
    printf("%d,", myName[i]);
}
puts("\n");

// prints char value of each element in string literal array
for (i = 0; i < length2; i++) {
    printf("%c,", name[i]);
}
puts("");
// prints int value of each element in string literal array
for (i = 0; i < length2; i++) {
    printf("%d,", name[i]);
}
puts("");
```

Here's the output:

```
Hayden, size: 7
Hayden, size: 8
H,a,y,d,e,n,,
72,97,121,100,101,110,0,

H,a,y,d,e,n,,%,
72,97,121,100,101,110,0,37,
```

I asked my professor about it, and he said it might be an issue with the code, but it's hard to mess up so few lines of simple code. Thanks in advance your consideration.

Comment: `sizeof(name);` is not the length of the string!

Comment: `sizeof()` returns the size of a variable in bytes. `name` is a pointer, in your case, you are obviously using a 64bit compiler, so `name` is 8 bytes long.  If you recompiled this with a 32bit compiler, you would find  the result of `sizeof(name)` would be 4, as 32bit pointers are 4 bytes long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator, is not meant to compute the length of a string. In your case `sizeof(char *)` is apparently 8 and `"Hayden"` has only 6 characters, so you are printing one character after the end of the actual string literal (*which is the **null** terminator*).

In the case of `myName` since it's an array, `sizeof` is actually giving you the number of elements of the array because `sizeof(char)` is 1.

When you print the element after the end of the array, your program invokes undefined behavior. The printed value would change if you change your program a little, and it actually seems to be one of the `"%"` in the format specifiers in your `printf()` statements which are also string literals.

You can't however predict what this element is going to be, it's just a coincidence, try changing the `printf()` statements a little and you will see the difference.

Comment: ok that makes sense. so when using `sizeof(char *)`, I'm getting 8 since the pointer is 8 bytes long while using `sizeof(char)` gives me 7 because the array is 7 bytes long, one for each char in the name, plus the null char. Thanks for the clarification. Sorry for the elementary question.

Comment: @HaydenBraxton Code is _not_ using `sizeof(char)`.  Code is using `sizeof(myName)` which is like `sizeof(char[7])`.   `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1.

Answer (score 1):

The % is just some value in ram which you are not supposed to read. As pointed out by @BeyelerStudios in the comments, `sizeof` is not the correct way to find out how long a string is, use `strlen` for that.

Answer (score 1):

`myName` is an array of characters, 7 characters long, each `char` is 1 byte so it returns 7, if it was an array of 7 integers, each `int` is 4 bytes in size, so it would return 28 as `sizeof()` always returns the size in bytes it occupies in memory.  `name` is a pointer to memory, which is 4 bytes long for 32 bit, 8 bytes long for 64bit. You should always use `strlen()` to obtain the length of C strings.